# Why i can run my android apps in my own laptop that are successfully run in my school lab with android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am interesting in create my own android apps, I have create myself a simple BMI calculation apps in school lab and it run successfully. But when I come home and try to run in my own laptop it doesn't run and prompt a message error. Below are the Message error:

> Installation failed with message Invalid File: E:\Degree
>   year2sem2\mobile
>   app\Pratical\Pratical2\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk.

It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?"

btw I am using android studio 3.0 and my school lab is using 2.3, can this be the version problem or anything? thanks  if anyone can help out

Comment: diff pc diff workplace setting.. try to click on `clean project` and `rebuild project`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by 3 steps:

> 1)Click Build tab -> Clean Project
>
> 2)Click Build tab -> Rebuild Project
>
> 3)Click Build tab -> Build APK

If that does not work,try

> Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment>Instant Run>Enable Instant Run to hot swap code(Uncheck this)

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are trying to run a part of the apk.

When you run your code android studio will create multiple slice of your application for faster running called `Instant run`.

> Build > Clean Project

Will remove all the slice apk from your local file.

Then run again

Comment: Thanks  a lot for your help